# I want to type 140 characters in asp.net textbox with multiline characters will be decreased as i type in textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to type 140 characters in asp.net textbox with multi line when I type in textbox then the characters will be decreaded means if I type two characters in textbox then in label the available characters will be shown is 138 using vb.net

Comment: If you don't take care in formulating your question accurately, nobody will take care in answering your question, because it is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a javascript method to calculate and length of the textarea and call it on the onkeyup event of the textarea.